# If and Else with TwiML?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

guys! I know how to make this using PHP, but can I do it directly in TwiML from Twilio's Console?

---

If 9AM-5PM, Mon-Fri:

```
<Response>
    <Dial answerOnBridge="true"><Sip>{{To}}@XXX.sip.us.twilio.com</Sip></Dial>
</Response>
```

Else:

```
<Response>
    <Say>XXX</Say>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

TwiML Bins, in the Twilio console, only have access to basic templating (the `{{To}}` you used in your example). They cannot perform more complicated logic though.

If you want to build this within the Twilio console, you can build it in JavaScript using [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions).